# Dagger 2 component inheritance and errors

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm trying to create the following scenario:

```
public interface DaggerInjectionFactory {
    void inject(MyActivity myActivity);
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {RestModule.class})
public interface MyRestComponent extends DaggerInjectionFactory {
    RestClient provideRestClient();
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {PreferencesModule.class})
public interface MyPreferencesComponent extends DaggerInjectionFactory {
    SharedPreferences provideSharedPreferences();       
}
```

The dagger compiler gives me the following error as a response:

```
error: RestClient cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
```

The `RestModule` contains a `@Provides @Singleton RestClient provideRestClient()` method and it is also worth noting that when I remove the `extends DaggerInjectionFactory` from the `MyPreferencesComponent` the dagger compiler has no issue in generating the component builders.

What I'm trying to do is create an interface with all the injectable classes, in which I want to use the `@Inject` annotation, and implement them in 'all' of my components so I don't have to add the `void inject(MyActivity myActivity);` to all of my components.

Because I'm new to the framework I have no idea what the correct terminology is and therefore have no real clue as to what I need to search for.

So my questions are: is it possible to create such a structure, to define an interface which automatically adds all the `void inject()` methods to 'all' of my components? and if so, how can it be done?

-- Edit --
The expected usage would be something like:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity {
    private RestClient restClient;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyRestComponent.Instance.build().inject(this);
        MyPreferencesComponent.Instance.build().inject(this);
    }

    @Inject
    public void setRestClient(RestClient restClient){
        this.restClient = restClient;
    }

    @Inject
    public void setSharedPreferences(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences){
        this.sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could  you provide some (pseudo-) code of what you're trying to achieve, or how you'd like to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create components for each module. You can just add more modules to component and as provide all classes in on this one interface.

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = {RestModule.class, PreferencesModule.class}
)
    public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(MainApplication app)
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

if you are asking for inject component to all activites/fragment/MainApplication there is no method for this. You have to specify which of these above will get dependency injection.